# Moving command line application to Windows Forms

Tags: c++, winforms

**I am using simplified version of the project what I ma looking for is a idea of how to do it in Windows Forms**

I have a working command line application. It is a simple school assignment program. The main player of this application is a Database class:

**database.h**

```
class Database{
  public:
    Database(string name);
    void add(...)
    void remove(...)
    //and so on more methods and other stuff
}
```

I can use it in my main.cpp:

```
include "database.h"

int main(){
   Database db("test");
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Three dots from this simple example represent all the different thing I can do with that database. **db** object is available in the main scope.

**How can I make instance of the  Database, available to all the windows in a Windows Form project?**

**Where/How should I instantiate Database object to be available to all forms?**

I would basically like to include my excising database.h file, instantiate the object out of it and be able to use it in different windows in the application.

I am using VS 2010 Ultimate.

Comment: Note that Microsofts Winforms are not C++. C++/CLI isn´t the same, even if it has "C++" in the name. If you want a pure C++ solution, get some other GUI framework.

Comment: I realize this but all I need to do in this application is to create few forms/windows and play with Box->Text fields. Database object will do all the heavy lifting if I manage to instantiate it globally some how! Can you suggest any other framework? I have tons of other subjects I need to go through and need something simple:(